# Calling a non-static function in a different file

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I have an issue with calling a non-static function from one file to another. Here are my codes:

```
package me.zoteuh.grillade;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public final class Grillade extends JavaPlugin {
    private static Grillade instance;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        instance = this;

        AnvilListener anvilListener = new AnvilListener();
        anvilListener.loadHeadTextures();

        checkFiles();
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(anvilListener, this);
        getLogger().info("Grillade Plugin Operational!");
    }

    public static Grillade getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private void checkFiles() {
        if (!getDataFolder().exists()) {
            if (getDataFolder().mkdir()) {
                getLogger().info("Grillade folder created.");
            } else {
                getLogger().severe("Unable to create the Grillade folder.");
            }
        }

        File headsFile = new File(getDataFolder(), "heads.json");
        if (!headsFile.exists()) {
            try {
                String defaultHeadsJson = "[\n]";
                Files.write(headsFile.toPath(), defaultHeadsJson.getBytes());
                getLogger().info("Created heads.json file.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Error creating heads.json file.", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
package me.zoteuh.grillade;

import com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile;
import com.mojang.authlib.properties.Property;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.PrepareAnvilEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.AnvilInventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.SkullMeta;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class AnvilListener implements Listener {
    private final Map<String, String> headTextures = new HashMap<>();

    @EventHandler
    public void onAnvilPrepare(PrepareAnvilEvent event) {
        loadHeadTextures();

        AnvilInventory anvilInventory = event.getInventory();
        ItemStack[] contents = anvilInventory.getContents();

        ItemStack firstInput = contents[0];
        ItemStack secondInput = contents[1];
        String renameText = event.getInventory().getRenameText();

        List<Material> classicHeads = new ArrayList<>();
        classicHeads.add(Material.CREEPER_HEAD);
        classicHeads.add(Material.SKELETON_SKULL);
        classicHeads.add(Material.ZOMBIE_HEAD);

        if (firstInput != null && secondInput == null && classicHeads.contains(firstInput.getType()) &&
                renameText != null && headTextures.containsKey(renameText)) {

            String texture = headTextures.get(renameText);
            ItemStack customHead = createCustomHead(texture, renameText);
            event.setResult(customHead);
        }
    }

    private ItemStack createCustomHead(String texture, String name) {
        ItemStack skull = new ItemStack(Material.PLAYER_HEAD);
        SkullMeta skullMeta = (SkullMeta) skull.getItemMeta();

        GameProfile profile = new GameProfile(UUID.randomUUID(), null);
        profile.getProperties().put("textures", new Property("textures", texture));

        try {
            Field profileField = skullMeta.getClass().getDeclaredField("profile");
            profileField.setAccessible(true);
            profileField.set(skullMeta, profile);
            skullMeta.setDisplayName(name);
            skull.setItemMeta(skullMeta);

            return skull;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void loadHeadTextures() {
        File jsonFile = new File(Grillade.getInstance().getDataFolder(), "heads.json");
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage("Chargement des textures");

        if (!jsonFile.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(jsonFile);
            JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseReader(reader);
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray headsArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("heads");


            for (JsonElement headElement : headsArray) {
                JsonObject headObject = headElement.getAsJsonObject();
                String name = headObject.get("name").getAsString();
                String texture = headObject.get("texture").getAsString();

                headTextures.put(name, texture);
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue arises from the function "loadHeadTextures." I would like to call it within the "onEnable" function in my main file.

I tried to do it by creating an instance as explained on this website but that didn't work
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/java/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java.html

I tried several other tips found here but none of them worked either..
The issue doesn't come from my function "loadHeadTextures". I tried calling it in its own file and it worked; the broadcast showed up correctly in the chat. However, as soon as I try to call it from the main file, it doesn't work. I don't have any errors, but nothing happens.

Comment: Can you explain what "didn't work?"  That absolutely should work, and at first glance your code looks ok, so more details what is wrong would help.  Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: *"I don't have any errors, but nothing happens."* Considering you have no error messages, the issue might not be with calling the non-static method. I suggest you try some debugging. Run the code in a debugger, setting some breakpoints. From a breakpoint, you can proceed one-step-at-a-time. You can abort the program, change the set break points, and try to narrow it down.  Another approach is to add code to display where where the program was, e.g., `System.out.println ("Entering checkFiles ()");`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not due to calling a non-static method in a different file. The broadcast message is not printed to the server because using `Bukkit.broadcastMessage()` does not work in `onEnable()` method. This is because the server is not fully started when the method is called.
Try using `System.out.println()` instead to display your message (as it seems to be used for debug purpose) or delay it by some ticks with a scheduler if you really want a broadcast.